# How to take the partial derivative of $f(x,y) = x\ln(x) + y\ln(y), x + y = 1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, constraints, constraint-programming

Let $f(x,y) = x\ln(x) + y\ln(y)$ be defined on space

$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x> 0, y > 0, x + y = 1\}$.

My question is, how do I take the partial derivative for this function, given that the parameters are coupled through $x+y = 1$.

A first idea would be to do it ignoring the coupling constraint. For this, we will get,

$\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} =  \dfrac{\partial x\ln(x) + y\ln(y)}{\partial x} 
 = \ln(x) + x/x = \ln(x) + 1$

If we do not ignore the coupling constraint, and instead substitute $y = 1-x$, we will get,

$\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} =  \dfrac{\partial x\ln(x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x)}{\partial x}  = \ln(x) + 1 + \dfrac{1}{1-x} - \ln(1-x) - \dfrac{x}{1-x}$

Am I doing this correctly?

Why do I get two different expressions of the gradient?

Comment: you can't use $y=1-x$, these variables are independent.

Comment: The $f$ on the first line is the function on all of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^2$, but the second is only on $S$ which only has the coordinate $x$ left. I presume you want the second case because you want to only do the entropy change as you change $p$.

Comment: I don't think this question makes sense. What do you even *mean* by partial derivatives in this situation? By definition, you are supposed to vary $x$ and hold $y$ constant when you take the partial of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, but you can't do that if you insist on having the constraint $x+y=1$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Why not write that comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you feels that it answers your question...

Answer (score 1):

Taking the partial of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ means that you vary $x$ while holding $y$ constant, but you can't do that if you insist on fulfilling the constraint $x+y=1$, so it's doesn't really make sense to talk about partial derivatives in this situation.

(You can eliminate $y$ and get a one-variable function $g(x)=f(x,1-x)$, but what you are computing then is an *ordinary* derivative $g'(x)$.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $y=1−x$, these variables are independent. Although we choose our points from 
$$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x> 0, y > 0, x + y = 1\}$$
but it doesn't mean these variables are dependent. Then the substitute $y = 1-x$ makes no sense in this **two variables function**.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean that the variables are independent? Independent means to me that you can choose as large as value of $x,y$ as you want without affecting each other. But clearly, for instance, I cannot let $x = 2$. Because there does not exist any $y$ such that $x+y =1, (x,y) \in S$.

Comment: Although choosing $x$ is affecting on $y$, $y$ isn't a function of $x$. We only restrict ourselves to choose $x$ and $y$ from $S$.

Comment: If you only have $50\$$, so you can buy two items with prices not exceed $50\$$. This doesn't mean the first item (cheese) is affecting on the second (shoe).